# replace string with date value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

Currently, I have a Derived Column transformation within my package that will look for a `NULL` value and if it is `NULL` it will give it a default date with forwarding slashes as seen below

```
REPLACENULL([date],"2/2/1999")
```

However, if that field is Not `NULL` it will have a string date which will look like `20200202`. I am wanting to add on to the current expression to where if the field is not null that it replaces `20200202` with `2020-02-02`. I would appreciate the help and will rate it highly!

Comment: Why are you using formatted string at all; SSIS supports date and time data types and you should be using them. `'2/2/1999'` has a clear value, but what about `'1/2/2020'`? Is that 01 February or January 2?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do that in SQL Server.

**Note**: `FORMAT` requires SQL Server 2012+

```
DECLARE @StringDate varchar(20);

    -- NON-NULL date.
    SET @StringDate = '20200202'
    SELECT
        ISNULL ( FORMAT( CAST ( @StringDate AS date ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ), '2/2/1999' ) AS NonNullStringDate;

    -- NULL date.
    SET @StringDate = NULL;
    SELECT
        ISNULL ( FORMAT( CAST ( @StringDate AS date ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ), '2/2/1999' ) AS NullStringDate;
```

Returns (respectively)

```
+-------------------+
| NonNullStringDate |
+-------------------+
| 2020-02-02        |
+-------------------+

+----------------+
| NullStringDate |
+----------------+
| 2/2/1999       |
+----------------+
```

For date formatting consistency, you may want to consider changing `2/2/1999` to `1999-2-2`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `1999-02-02` as a default value to make sure that all values are stored in the same format. The following expression will convert the date format from `yyyyMMdd` to `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```
REPLACENULL([date],"") == "" ? "1999-02-02" : LEFT([date],4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([date],5,2) + "-" + RIGHT([date],2)
```